# Kotlin with-statement as an expression

Tags: kotlin

We can do

```
val obj = Obj()
with (obj) {
    objMethod1()
    objMethod2()
}
```

But is there a way to do this?

```
val obj = with(Obj()) {
    objMethod1()
    objMethod2()
}
```

To solve a common case where you create an object and call a few methods on it to initialise its state.

Comment: AFAIR, you can use `val obj = Obj().apply { ... }`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [`.apply { }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) stdlib function, which

> Calls the specified function *block* with `this` value as its receiver and returns `this` value.

```
public inline fun <T> T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T { block(); return this }
```

Usage example:

```
val obj = Obj().apply {
    objMethod1()
    objMethod2()
}
```

You can find it among many other Kotlin idioms [here in the reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#builder-style-usage-of-methods-that-return-unit).

Answer (score 7):

Your second example works too - just make sure that the lambda returns the correct value (the result of the last expression is the returned value of the `with` expression):

```
val obj = with(Obj()) {
   objMethod1()
   objMethod2()
   this   // return 'this' because we want to assign the new instance to obj
}
```